# arrayListOf showing Int rather than String - Kotlin

Tags: android, string, kotlin, arraylist

I am trying to get string value from string file like this:

```
var language = arrayListOf<String>(
    R.string.All_Categories.toString(),
    
)
```

but it shows an Int rather than a string like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***SOLUTION:***

first, in OnCreate must define the string:

```
val Profile_Settings = resources.getString(R.string.ProfileSettings)
```

second, add the value to the array:

```
var language2 = arrayListOf<String>(
        Profile_Settings,
        
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

`R.string.All_Categories` is the id, not the string itself

To get the string you need to use

`var value = getString(R.string.All_Categories)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are doing `toString` on the generated reference. You should instead use `R.array.All_Categories` if that is the name of your referenced array. For example, you have the following in the resources file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="my_books">
        <item>Scala Cookbook</item>
        <item>Play Framework Recipes</item>
        <item>How I Sold My Business: A Personal Diary</item>
        <item>A Survival Guide for New Consultants</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

This is how you would want to read it in the code.

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] myBooks = res.getStringArray(R.array.my_books);
```

Kotlin code example in fragment:

```
val res: Resources = resources
val myBooks: Array<String> = res.getStringArray(R.array.my_books)
```

You can use `.toList()` on the `Array<String>` to convert it to a collections object like the `arrayListOf<String>` expected by you.

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple, you just have to use `getString(your_string_id)` and you are good to go!

which looks like this:

```
val data = getString(R.string.all_categories)
```